# Shimming javascript assets using Browserify / Webpack (ES6 or CommonJS)

Tags: javascript, webpack, browserify, browserify-shim, react-redux

How does one shimming javascript correctly and without extra files using either browserify or webpack?

Let's take example of using react or react-redux. I have this configuration in package.json:

```
{
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify",
        {
          "presets": [
            "es2015",
            "react"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:$",
    "react": "global:React",
    "react-addons-update": "global:React.addons.update",
    "react-dom": "global:ReactDOM",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-addons-update": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "uglify-js": "~2.5.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.1.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "browserify-shim": "~3.8.12",
    "clean-css": "~3.4.6",
    "eslint": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.1.0",
  }
}
```

In my project, I uses react-redux with line `import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';`, and I added react-redux as a dependency.
When I compiled my project, it results to one javascript file with around 20K lines.

The problem is, when I shim react-redux, by using cdnjs (`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.0/react-redux.js`) of react-redux and add it to browserify-shim configuration, my project only uses around 2K lines, and react-redux js file alone only uses around 700 lines (And the project still works!).

Why it is happen? Can I not adding react-redux in browserify-shim but still only added 700 lines to my compiled project javascript instead of 18K lines?

What magic is actually happening here, and how does the magic actually works?

Answer (score 0):

When you use react-redux through the CDN with `"global:react-redux"`, browserify-shim is simply asking the js bundle to call the already-loaded global variable via the `window`. For instance, in a test I ran my browserified bundle had only eight lines. The first is browserify-shim boilerplate in one long line, and the last seven do exactly what I described above:

```
(function (global){
(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window['$'] : typeof global !== "undefined" ? global['$'] : null);
(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window['react-redux'] : typeof global !== "undefined" ? global['react-redux'] : null);
(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window['react'] : typeof global !== "undefined" ? global['react'] : null);

}).call(this,typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {}) 
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

When you actually bundle the packages in the browserified bundle (meaning they are not loaded via CDN), the bundle must include all of that source code. I tried this again with the same packages: jQuery, React, and React-redux, and rather than seven lines in my bundle I got over 30,000 lines. This makes sense because the entire jQuery, React, React-redux packages are included in that bundle.

Without seeing your full `package.json` and output files it would be difficult to say more. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, the browserify-shim only check the global variable. But the react-redux.js from cdn itself only 700 lines. Is there any way so instead of appending 20K lines, it's appending 700 lines? It works with the 700, why should I uses the 20K lines?

Comment: Is your question then, "why is `react-redux.js` 700 lines when loaded via CDN and 20,000 lines when loaded via browserify?" You would have to post the `<script>` tag you're using to load it via CDN and your full `package.json` file. The most likely explanation is that one is minified and the other is not, or that the CDN concatenates lines that the npm version does not. They're the exact same packages.

Comment: I updated my questions to add `package.json` dependencies, and the cdn url. The cdn file is not minified or uglified.